# Python - TypeError: Unhashable type list error

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to create a comprehension that takes each value n in a list and returns the values from 1-n.
I.E. for `[1,2,4]` the return should be `[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3,4]]`.
My code is getting this `unhashable type list` error.

```
 {range(x) for x in {1,2,4}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Braces - `{}`* creates a Set of the element you pass to it. To create a list, you need to use *brackets - `[]`*

```
[range(x) for x in [1,2,4]]
```

And to get the required output, you need to change your `range()` a little bit. `range(2)` will give you `[0, 1]` instead of `[1, 2]`.

You can use:

```
>>> [range(1, x+1) for x in [1, 2, 4]]
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: @Brian. Yeah only when you pass elements in the form of `key:value` pair. `{1, 2, 3}` creates a `set([1, 2, 3])`, whereas, `{"a":1, "b":2}` creates a dict.